# Consulta em duas tabelas Oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql

Como faço para consultar duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo? Tenho duas estruturas de tabelas da seguinte forma.

```
TGFCAB
___________________
|NUNOTA|   DTMOV  |
------------------|
|  1   |01/06/2019|
|  2   |02/06/2019|
|  3   |03/06/2019|
```

e

```
TGFITE

|NUNOTA|CODPROD|QTDNEG|VLRUNIT |VLRTOTAL|
|------|-------|------|--------|--------|
|  1   |  18   |5,2   |10      |52      |
|  1   |  26   |1,3   |10      |13      |
|  2   |  11   |10,5  |10      |105     |   
|  2   |  26   |16,5  |10      |165     |
|  2   |  18   |2,5   |10      |250     |
|  3   |  18   |2,0   |10      |200     |
```

No caso eu fiz um SELECT na primeira tabela, para procurar os valores do dia 01/06/2019 e 02/06/2019, ficou da seguinte forma.

```
SELECT * FROM TGFCAB 
    WHERE DTMOV
        BETWEEN 
            to_date('01-JUN-19', 'dd-mon-yy')
        AND 
            to_date('02-JUN-19', 'dd-mon-yy')
    ORDER BY DTMOV;
```

Preciso agora automaticamente pegar somente as notas fiscais 1 e 2, que são respectivamente dos dias 1 e 2. Há alguma forma de fazer isso sem ter de digitar manual?

Comment: Uma junção entre as duas tabelas via campo NUNOTA? Uma INNER JOIN fornecerá o que necessita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode fazer

```
SELECT * 
FROM TGFCAB
INNER JOIN TGFITE
ON TGFCAB.NUNOTA = TGFITE.NUNOTA 
WHERE TGFCAB.DTMOV
    BETWEEN 
        to_date('01-JUN-19', 'dd-mon-yy')
    AND 
        to_date('02-JUN-19', 'dd-mon-yy')
ORDER BY TGFCAB.DTMOV;
```

Comment: Funcionou! Uma ótima coisa a se fazer no código também é atribuir um "alias" para cada tabela, assim não precisando rescrever o nome completo dela durante o código.